# Can't locate XML/Simple.pm in @INC after install

Tags: perl, cpan

When I run my perl script, I keep getting this error:
`Can't locate XML/Simple.pm in @INC after install`

I have installed a bunch of modules, including `Bundle::CPANxxl` with CPAN.

The first time I ran/installed CPAN, I executed it as root:

```
$ sudo cpan
```

Then again:

```
$ sudo cpan
cpan> install Bundle::CPANxxl
cpan> install Xml::Simple
```

When I run my Perl script, I still get the `Can't locate XML/Simple.pm in @INC...` error in Apache "error.log"

I have run the following with and without root:

```
cpan> install XML::Simple
cpan> upgrade
cpan> realod cpa
```

Why am I getting this error all the time, even though I have installed the module several times? Please can I have some advice on this issue?

Comment: Solved the XML::Simple issue with `apt-get install libxml-simple-perl` but it seems I only solved one problem as now there is a second Perl mod that "Can't be located". Still need to figure out why Perl is not finding the other libs...

Answer (score 13):

just

`$ cpan install XML::Simple`

work for me , maybe its because lowcase caracter : Xml and not XML

Answer (score 4):

I ran into a similar issue and installing the missing lib as @chubeez mentionned in his comments long ago solved the problem.

`apt-get install libxml-simple-perl`

I rewrote it here as an answer to give it more visibility.

Answer (score 1):

```
$ sudo cpan XML::Simple
```

Above command works for me

Answer (score 0):

In conda environment, following commands worked for me:

```
conda install -c conda-forge perl-xml-parser
cpan install XML::Simple
```